# R system functions always returns error 127

Tags: r, shell, error-handling, system, system2

I need to execute an  external tool from **`R`** and process errors (if any) occurred in that tool.
I know 3 functions to do something familiar with my task:

```
shell, system and system2.
```

Trying to test those, I see that command

```
shell("notepad")
```

opens notepad. As far as I know shell doesn't allow to check errors (there's no interface to look into `stderr`).

When I call

```
system("notepad")
```

or

```
system2("notepad")
```

**`R`** freezes trying to make those commands.

Calling

```
system("start notepad")
```

or

```
system2("start notepad")
```

returns warning

```
Warning message:
running command '"start notepad"' had status 127
```

Comment: The problem boils down to `notepad` not being in the PATH and therefore is not visible to R for executing it.  On my machine, I can call `system("java -version")` with no trouble.  Strangely, I could not get Notepad to launch from R even after adding it to my PATH.

Comment: I can also get `system("git version")` to work.  There may be an issue with non command line programs in R.  Why do you want to launch Notepad from R may I ask?

Comment: > system("git version")
Warning message:
running command 'git version' had status 127

Comment: Yes, because `git` is not on your `PATH`.  Type `echo %PATH%` from a command prompt and you will see this.

Comment: shell("notepad")  opens notepad, so notepad is in my PATH

Comment: Yes, this just worked for me as well.  It seems like `system()` cannot launch a new window.  So it hangs for Notepad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments, the R documentation reveals that in Windows the `system()` function does not launch a separate shell (if needed).  This is why command line commands run with `system()`, but Notepad, which needs a separate window, does not run:

From the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) for `system()`:

> The most important difference is that on a Unix-alike system launches a shell which then runs command. On Windows the command is run directly – **use shell for an interface which runs command via a shell** (by default the Windows shell cmd.exe, which has many differences from a POSIX shell).

Answer (score 23):

Adapting @DavidTseng's answer (sorry for not having enough reputation to upvote it)...

```
system("cmd.exe", input = "notepad")
```

worked for me in Windows.

Comment: This is very useful in several ways - for instance, `system("cmd.exe", input = "tree > Tree.txt /A /F")` will make a file `Tree.txt` containing a directory tree with all folders, subfolders and files.

Answer (score 4):

```
system("bash -l", input = "notepad")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's been an update to R that allows this since the question was asked nearly four years ago, but `system("\"C:\path\to\exe.exe\" args", intern = T)` works for me and WILL bring up a separate child window and works on Windows 10 + R 3.6 + RStudio.

Not using the 'intern = T' was giving me a return code of 127 and did not run the process.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. there is an additional step in the installation process which i did not do.

## refer to to the url

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

## Look for "Putting Rtools on the PATH"

writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\usr\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")

Answer (score 0):

for windows users
wrong: `system(path("c:", "program files", "r", "anysoft.EXE"))`
but works : `system(path("c:", shQuote("program files"), "r", "anysoft.EXE"))`

Answer (score -3):

You guys are making it so complicated. I solved this problem by referring to [this answer](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problem-Invoking-System-Commands-from-R-td4698188.html). The problem is with the PATH. type `Sys.which('')` in R, and you will see nothing. So you have to set the path in CMD, and then use `Sys.setenv(PATH = '')` in R to get this work.