# How do I open a document from R?

Tags: r, shell, cmd, launch

I want to open a file from within R.

I can launch the software (graphpad prism) with the following:

```
system2("C:/Program Files (x86)/GraphPad/Prism 7/prism.exe")
```

I expected this to open my prism file as if I were double clicking on it or running it from cmd, but it didn't:

```
system2("H:/Graphs/Shell/Templates/NASH4_Standard.pzfx")
```

I am receiving the message:

> Warning message: running command
>   'H:/Graphs/Shell/Templates/NASH4_Standard.pzfx' had status 127

I see that this is not an error but just a warning. Am I unintentionally "shelling" the document in the background? How would I make sure it pops up as a window?

Status 127 was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646816/r-system-functions-always-returns-error-127), but for launching the software, not opening the document with it.

Comment: Are `.pzfx` files associated with the `prism.exe` application by default? If not, you may need to pass the `.pzfx` file as an argument to the first command.

Comment: When I double click a `.pzfx` file, it launches with `prism.exe`. Same if I copy `"H:/Graphs/Shell/Templates/NASH4_Standard.pzfx"` to cmd. Does that mean it is associated?

Comment: Probably; does `edit(file = "path/to/file.pzfx", editor = "path/to/prism.exe")` work for you?

Comment: This works, but without the path. As my working directory was already set to the folder the file was in, `edit(file = "NASH4_Standard.pzfx", editor = "C:/Program Files (x86)/GraphPad/Prism 7/prism.exe")` worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows environments, you need to call a command line interpreter like CMD prompt or PowerShell. Also, any file path that has spaces needs to be enclosed in double quotes above the quotes needed in R for string literals (the case for your .exe not specific file).

With `system()` send entire command in one string:

```
system('cmd /c "H:/Graphs/Shell/Templates/NASH4_Standard.pzfx"')

# POWER SHELL REQUIRES MORE QUOTE ESCAPING (ONLY ONE PAIR W/O SPACES)
system('powershell & """H:/Graphs/Shell/Templates/NASH4_Standard.pzfx"""')
```

With `system2()` use the *args* parameter:

```
# FILES
system2('cmd', args=c('/c', '"H:/Graphs/Shell/Templates/NASH4_Standard.pzfx"'))
system2('powershell', args=c(' & """H:/Graphs/Shell/Templates/NASH4_Standard.pzfx"""'))

# EXECUTABLES
system2('cmd', args=c('/c', '"C:/Program Files (x86)/GraphPad/Prism 7/prism.exe"'))
system2('powershell', args=c(' & """C:/Program Files (x86)/GraphPad/Prism 7/prism.exe"""'))
```

Answer (score 2):

`shell.exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/GraphPad/Prism 7/prism.exe")`

does it work for you ?

ps. and `shell.exec("MyWorkbook.xls")` open file with default program