# Calling command line from R - error 127

Tags: r, command, line

I'm trying to call command line from R. A simple example of this is:

> system(paste("cd",getwd() ))

However, I get the following error message:

> > Warning message: running command 'cd >>C:/Users/ had status 127

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646816/r-system-functions-always-returns-error-127

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R system functions always returns error 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646816/r-system-functions-always-returns-error-127)