# How to launch Microsoft Edge from R?

Tags: r, windows, shiny

I was originally trying to force my shiny apps to launch in Edge

```
options(browser = "C:/Windows/SystemApps/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/MicrosoftEdge.exe")
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Furthermore, I can't even launch Microsoft Edge from windows command line using this path to the exe, but instead, you have to use this in the command line:

```
start microsoft-edge:
```

But then you can't use R's `system()` to launch edge this way:

```
> system("start microsoft-edge:")
Warning message:
running command 'start microsoft-edge:' had status 127
```

Any ideas on how to use Microsoft edge with R?

Comment: This may be of your interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646816/r-system-functions-always-returns-error-127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get to Edge using

```
system("cmd.exe", input="start microsoft-edge:")
```

Comment: This could also be written as: `shell("start microsoft-edge:")`

Comment: `start msedge` also works, I believe this is because `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\msedge.exe` is within the registry on windows