# R always returns error 127 when using shell()

Tags: r, shell, error-handling, environment-variables, system

I'm sourcing a code that need to execute an .exe file that runs a retrospective analysis for a stock assessment model.

it is when my loop reach following piece of code that it gives an error message.

```
shell(paste( file.path(data.path,'retro',"sms.exe"),"-nox -nohess",sep=" "), invisible = TRUE)
```

> ```
> Warning message:
> In shell(paste(file.path(data.path, "retro", "sms.exe"), "-nox -nohess",  :
>   'M:/Sprat/Sprat_assessment/SMS_2023/Sprat-div-4_plus_IIIa_exploreBound2/retro/sms.exe -nox -nohess' had status error 127
> ```

The code is running on an external driver, and I've recently updated R, using newest R-version 4.2.2, with newest versions of Rtools in Windows.

My colleagues can run the code successfully from their computer using windows, but I cannot.
Any reasons why I cannot run the code and get the error message.
Is their a way to set the path or allow my R to have the path in its internal enviroment?

I've already tried problems-solving from [using system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646816/r-system-functions-always-returns-error-127), but since the code are hardwired for work processes and should not be changed this is not an optimal choice. So I need for my R execution to work with the same coding.

Comment: Have you tried running `M:/Sprat/Sprat_assessment/SMS_2023/Sprat-div-4_plus_IIIa_exploreBound2/retro/sms.exe -nox -nohess` outside of R at the command line? Does that work? Is the problem only when you try to run it inside of R?

Comment: Does ``paste0('"',file.path(data.path,'retro',"sms.exe"), '"')`` change anything?

Comment: Note that in POSIX shells exit status 127 means "command not found". Does the R "shell" function actually run the command line via "shell -c ..."? If, instead, it is using that command line as the command to run that would explain the error since you're appending the arguments to the command path.

Comment: @MrFlick Running _M:/Sprat/Sprat_assessment/SMS_2023/Sprat-div-4_plus_IIIa_exploreBound2/retro/sms.exe -nox -nohess_ outside in com. promt does not work. Furthermore paste0() is is not an optimal choice for code that are work-related and should not be changed.

Comment: @KurtisRader, as I stated above, then my colleagues can run the code successfully from their computer using windows, but I cannot - so it seems that it is my R-setup rather than anything else.

Comment: If it doesn't work at the command prompt then it doesn't seem to be related to R. You need to be able to run the program outside of R first. Once you got that, then you can figure out how to run it inside of R.